# pip.exe and others close on startup

Tags: python, crash, pip, windows-10

When I open up the pip.exe, pip3.exe or pip3.5.exe (or any of the easy_install.exe) I have in my

> \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts

folder they open but close as soon as they open. No error is displayed, but while the program is open, I can see what must be the help/commands used in pip for the short time until it closes. I am trying to install selenium for python. Is there any workaround/fix to this?

Comment: `pip` is a command line tool. You can only call it directly from the command line.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. To anybody curious how to do that first cd to your scripts folder, then type in "call pip" and its open :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in command prompt

```
pip {command} [options]
```

e.g. `pip install pyperclip`.